# issue with "%" MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a newbie question.

The "%" seems not working here whereas "Troyes" is in the database:

```
$requete = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM club where ville='Tro%'")->fetchall();
```

But here the fetchall give me what I want:

```
$requete = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM club where ville='Troyes'")->fetchall();
```

do you know what's wrong with the first query ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I think you're looking for "Like", check this out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: It's a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `=` with `LIKE`, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM club where ville LIKE 'Tro%'
```